# How long has it been since last card top-up?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a table for our stored-value cards:

```
CardNo   TransactionType   Amount    TransactionDate(datetime2)
         (1 for Top-up, 0 for purchasing products)
=========================================================
0001        1              1000.00    20170809(only date is displayed for brevity)
0001        0              200.00     20170810
0001        0              300.00     20170811
0001        1              200.00     20170811
0001        0              200.00     20170812
```

We would like to know for each card (customer), the time between each purchase and the most recent top-up at that time. So the intended result is:

```
RowID   GapDays
================
1       Null (or 0)
2       1
3       2
4       Null
5       1
```

> Why is there a gap of 2 days for a row id of 3?

The purchase happens before the top-up.

The date column is of type `datetime2`, has a "time" portion (omitted here for brevity), and the data is ordered by that. You may utilize any index. Non-existent index will be added if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added time part to the `TransactionDate` just to get the correct order for the transactions:

> ```
> create table cards(CardNo varchar(10), TransactionType int, Amount money, TransactionDate datetime2);
> create index ix_cards on cards(CardNo, TransactionType, TransactionDate);
> insert into cards values
> ('0001',        1,              1000.00,    '20170809 00:00:00'),
> ('0001',        0,              200.00,     '20170810 00:00:00'),
> ('0001',        0,              300.00,     '20170811 00:00:00'),
> ('0001',        1,              200.00,     '20170811 00:00:01'),
> ('0001',        0,              200.00,     '20170812 00:00:00');
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 5 rows affected
> ```

Then you can get it by using an `APPLY` operator with all records where `TransactionType = 1`. Note you must limit to one record the rows returned by the subquery.

> ```
> set statistics xml on;
>
> SELECT t1.CardNo, t1.TransactionType, t1.Amount, t1.TransactionDate, t3.TransactionDate,
>        DATEDIFF(DAY, t3.TransactionDate, t1.TransactionDate) GapDays
> FROM   cards t1
> OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 t2.TransactionDate
>              FROM   cards t2
>              WHERE  t2.CardNo = t1.CardNo
>              AND    t2.TransactionType = 1
>              AND    t2.TransactionDate <= t1.TransactionDate
>              ORDER BY t2.CardNo, t2.TransactionDate DESC) t3
> ORDER BY t1.CardNo, t1.TransactionType, t1.TransactionDate
> set statistics xml off;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> CardNo | TransactionType | Amount    | TransactionDate     | TransactionDate     | GapDays
> :----- | --------------: | :-------- | :------------------ | :------------------ | ------:
> 0001   |               0 | 200.0000  | 10/08/2017 00:00:00 | 09/08/2017 00:00:00 |       1
> 0001   |               0 | 300.0000  | 11/08/2017 00:00:00 | 09/08/2017 00:00:00 |       2
> 0001   |               0 | 200.0000  | 12/08/2017 00:00:00 | 11/08/2017 00:00:01 |       1
> 0001   |               1 | 1000.0000 | 09/08/2017 00:00:00 | 09/08/2017 00:00:00 |       0
> 0001   |               1 | 200.0000  | 11/08/2017 00:00:01 | 11/08/2017 00:00:01 |       0
> ```

[image: Execution plan]

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a257ea21b943abc431a5c0bf71e02532)*

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table (CardNo varchar(100),  TransactionType int,   Amount decimal(10,2),    TransactionDate datetime2);
    insert into @t values
    ('0001',        1,              1000.00,    '20170809'),
    ('0001',        0,              200.00,     '20170810'),
    ('0001',        0,              300.00,     '20170811 00:00:00'),
    ('0001',        1,              200.00,     '20170811 00:00:01'),
    ('0001',        0,              200.00,     '20170812');



select *, datediff(day, a.top_ud_dt, TransactionDate)as gap
from @t t1 outer apply ( select max(t2.TransactionDate) as top_ud_dt
                         from @t t2 
                         where t1.CardNo = t2.CardNo
                               and t2.TransactionType = 1
                               and t2.TransactionDate <= t1.TransactionDate) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
What happen when you have multiple cardno ?give example
```

Alternatively ,Same problem can be solve using `Sql server 2012 lag` function.
It is just for learning window function and how `scalar expression` can be dynamic

Not discussing performance here.

```
create table #cards(CardNo varchar(10), TransactionType int, Amount money
, TransactionDate datetime2);
create index ix_cards on #cards(CardNo, TransactionType, TransactionDate);
insert into #cards values
('0001', 1, 1000.00,'20170809 00:00:00'),
('0001', 0, 200.00, '20170810 00:00:00'),
('0001', 0, 300.00, '20170811 00:00:00'),
('0001', 1, 200.00, '20170811 00:00:01'),
('0001', 0, 200.00, '20170812 00:00:00');

GO
;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,CASE 
            WHEN TransactionType = 1
                THEN NULL
            ELSE lag((
                        SELECT TOP 1 TransactionDate
                        FROM #cards c1
                        WHERE TransactionType = 1
                            AND c1.TransactionDate < c.TransactionDate
                        ORDER BY c1.TransactionDate DESC
                        ), 0) OVER (
                    ORDER BY c.TransactionDate DESC
                    )
            END RecentTopUp
    FROM #cards c
    )
SELECT CardNo , TransactionType , Amount 
, TransactionDate 
    ,datediff(day, RecentTopUp, TransactionDate) GapDays
FROM cte


drop table #cards
```